# How to use zindex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the syntax for zindex?

I tried like this

```
document.getElementById('iframe_div1').style.zIndex =2000;
document.getElementById('iframe_div1').style.z-index =2000;
```

It is not working, it doesn't even show an error.

This is my snippet. It is working fine in HTML, but I want to set this CSS property in jQuery or JavaScript. The top/position attributes are not working...

> z-index:1200px; top:450px; position:absolute; right:300px;

```
document.getElementById('iframe_div1').style.display='block';
$("#iframe_div1").css("z-index", "500");
$("#iframe_div1").css("right", "300");
$("#iframe_div1").css("top", "450");
document.getElementById('iframe_div1').style.position = "absolute";
```

This snippet is not as perfect as I expect. I want to move my div center of the page, but it just moving my div to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Why not put the css line in cssText for the element?

Comment: Mixing jQuery and plain JS (for the same task) is not so good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The former should work all right. Use a DOM inspector like Firebug's "inspect element" to find out whether maybe the value gets assigned, but doesn't have the desired effect.

In jQuery, it would be

```
 $("#iframe_div1").css("z-index", "2000");
```

Comment: @Bharani what *about* position?

Answer (score 15):

`document.getElementById('iframe_div1').style.zIndex = "2000";` is fine. Just make sure it's `position` is `absolute` or `relative`. like this,

```
document.getElementById('iframe_div1').style.position = "relative"; // could also be absolute
```

Answer (score 3):

As this link mentions, `zIndex` only works if the element was positioned, so are you using something like `position: absolute;`?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_zindex.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#iframe_div1').css({
        right : '300px',
        top : '450px',
        border : '1px solid red',
        color : '#f00'
});
```

Thanks Problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

> ...but it just moving my div bottom of the page...

becouse:

```
document.getElementById('iframe_div1').style.display='block';
```

Must be:

```
document.getElementById('iframe_div1').style.display='relation';

//or

document.getElementById('iframe_div1').style.display='absolute';
```

Comment: No it is not. `absolute` is for `position`, not `display`. Please don't post wrong answer if you do not know much about the topic.